# Unable to create envelope with editor and signer as embedded recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I will be using my app credentials to create a document which should be edited by a editor recipient and should be signed by a signer recipient. It is failing with the below error though the recipient editor has a docusign account.

```
 com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: {
  "errorCode": "EDITOR_MUST_HAVE_ACCOUNT",
  "message": "The recipient Editor must be an existing DocuSign account member."
}
```

Below is my code -

```
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.setEmailSubject(referral.getEmailSubject());


//Envelope events - Sent, Delivered, Completed, Declined, or Voided
//Recipient events - Sent, Delivered, Completed, Declined, AuthenticationFailed, and AutoResponded

envDef.setDocuments(getDocuments());


Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
tabs.setTextTabs(getTextTabs(referral));

EventNotification eventNotification = new EventNotification();
eventNotification.setLoggingEnabled("true");
eventNotification.setUrl("https://staging.agentdesks.com/v1.0/postbox/docusign/crs/event");

List<EnvelopeEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
EnvelopeEvent event1 = new EnvelopeEvent();
event1.setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("completed");
events.add(event1);


EnvelopeEvent event2 = new EnvelopeEvent();
event2.setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("declined");
events.add(event2);

EnvelopeEvent event3 = new EnvelopeEvent();
event3.setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("voided");
events.add(event3);
eventNotification.setEnvelopeEvents(events);


envDef.setEventNotification(eventNotification);

Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
Editor editor = new Editor();
editor.setName(referral.getSender().getFirstname());
editor.setRecipientId(String.valueOf(referral.getSender().getIdFromMysql()));
editor.setEmail(referral.getSenderEmail());
editor.setClientUserId(String.valueOf(referral.getSender().getIdFromMysql()));
editor.setRoutingOrder("1");
editor.setRoleName("editor 1");
editor.setRequireIdLookup("false");
editor.setEmbeddedRecipientStartURL("www.google.com");

recipients.setEditors(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(editor)));

Signer signer = new Signer();
signer.setName(referral.getReceiver().getFirstname());
signer.setEmail(referral.getReceiver().getEmail());
signer.setRecipientId(String.valueOf(referral.getReceiver().getIdFromMysql()));
signer.setTabs(tabs);
signer.setClientUserId(String.valueOf(referral.getReceiver().getIdFromMysql()));
signer.setRoutingOrder("2");
signer.setRoleName("signer 2");
recipients.setSigners(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(signer)));

envDef.setRecipients(recipients);
envDef.setStatus("sent");


EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary =
           docusign.envelopeApi.createEnvelope(docusign.getAccountId(), envDef);
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error with node SDK. I think an error here makes sense. Although the error message should be different.

*clientUserId* is specified for embedded recipients where authentication is not handled by DocuSign and hence the receiver may not be a DocuSign user - [Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html).
Whereas an *editor* type recipient mandates a DocuSign account. Hence even if you were able to send *clientUserId* and get an embedded viewUrl in response, it would take you to DocuSign login page followed by envelope editor http://prntscr.com/cyvg96.

Or, I might be wrong and this is just a DocuSign bug. Just my thoughts.

Comment: Yes it should take him to docusign login page followed by envelope editor. Thats the expected thing here and thats what I am looking out for

Answer (score 1):

Vaibhav is right and this is not a bug. Although the error itself isn't explicit, it is correct; an embedded signer is inherently a non-accounted DocuSign user, yet the requirement for an editor is they are accounted.

Comment: But the OP said that the editor has an account with Docusign!